# How to import a .ev3 project file into Mindstorms software

Tags: ev3, software

My son just built this [Rubik's Cube solver](http://mindcuber.com/mindcub3r/mindcub3r.html) and I wanted to help him with the software aspect of it. Despite being a pretty big computer geek, I'm stumped!

The [software instructions](http://mindcuber.com/mindcub3r/mindcub3r.html#MindCub3rProgram) say to download the .zip, unpack it, and then open the project. Instructions make reference to 1.4.0 ("as of 1.4.0...") and also recommend updating to the latest version, so presumably the instructions were written when 1.4.x or higher was the current version.

I have 1.5.0 installed.

[image]

The instructions show this in the File menu:

[image]

I only have a File > Open open, and it only allows selecting two types of files, .lmsp and .lleu. Navigating to the extracted .zip folder indeed shows it as an empty directory despite the .ev3 file being in there.

[image]

This seems stupidly stupid, though I struck out googling my way out of this. I was doubting I even had the right mindstorm software installed, so I went down a rabbit hole, finding [this MS page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads) which seems exactly right, but ultimately links to [a nothing page](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/lego%AE-mindstorms%AE-ev3-home/9N7GN3KC2GK6?hl=en-us&gl=US&icmp=LP-SHQL-Standard-Mindstorms_download_quicklink_Windows-TH-MD-5VOFRVGWN5&rtc=1). More searching led me to think [this is the current software](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3/software/) to use for ev3 based kits, but upon install, I find it also only allows .lmsp and .lleu files.

Could someone kindly assist in pointing me in the right direction? Is it just that this project my son found is so old I have to track down an archived historical version of the software?

Answer (score 3):

I'd already written this and by guessing did indeed confirm the issue is just that `.ev3` files must be for an old version of Mindstorms software. I figured I might as well post the answer to help any others running into this and confused like I was.

I ultimately installed v1.4.5, which is what downloads from the section titled "Retired LEGO® MINDSTORMS® EV3 Home Edition software for PC and Mac" on [this page](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3/software/), which also looks to be the correct page for downloading the current (but "modern") version of Mindstorms software for EV3 sets.